# Why can't I set the object on a many modifiers?

Tags: modifiers, armature

In this specific case, I'm trying to apply an armature modifier but when I click on the dropdown menu no object names show up (see image), if I try to select the object with the eyedropper it says "failed to set value" if I press apply it says "modifier disabled, skipping apply" how do I get the modifier to work?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the object drop down menu of the armature modifier, you can select armature objects (bones), and not mesh objects.

Comment: how do I create bones?

Comment: use <kbd>shift a</kbd>menu > *Armature*